# How can I change Bootstrap columns sizing based on screen size?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have 6 items to display...

On a cell phone (xs) I want two rows of three items to display and on bigger than cell phone size, I'd like to see all six on the same row.

I tried...

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2'>1</div>
  <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2'>2</div>
  <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2'>3</div>
  <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2'>4</div>
  <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2'>5</div>
  <div class='col-xs-4 col-sm-2'>6</div>
</div>
```

This displays fine on a large screen with all 6 items but when viewing in the xs screen (phone) it just shows 6 separate rows.

I want to see

1   2   3   4   5   6

on large screen and

1   2   3

4   5   6

on xs screens.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `col-x` instead of `col-xs-x`. It was depreciated on bootstrap 4.

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">1</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">2</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">3</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">4</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">5</div>
    <div class="col-4 col-sm-2">6</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Any idea how I can put a little margin between these elements?  When I added mr-2 to the first 5 of 6 items it now wraps the sixth item to a new row.

Answer (score 3):

`col-xs-` was for Bootstrap-3. For Bootstrap-4, for the smallest screen, use `col-4,` so your code would look like:

```
<div class='row'>
  <div class='col-4 col-sm-2'>1</div>
  <div class='col-4 col-sm-2'>2</div>
  <div class='col-4 col-sm-2'>3</div>
  <div class='col-4 col-sm-2'>4</div>
  <div class='col-4 col-sm-2'>5</div>
  <div class='col-4 col-sm-2'>6</div>
</div>
```

That should give you three columns on a smartphone and six columns on anything else.

### Update for space between the elements:

If you want some spacing between your elements, you could put another column inside your first column, and then put your information in that column. The normal gutter is 15px wide, and with two gutters, the space between columns would be 30px. If that’s too wide, you can customize it as explained in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27005684/1011984

As an example, I revised my first solution to include a 5px gutter (so 10px total). I also put some spacing between the elements on a smartphone, and a block below the elements to illustrate that you can get right next to them, if you want. If you don’t, just delete the mb-n3 margin on the row.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<style>
    .row.gutter {
        margin-left: -5px;
        margin-right: -5px
    }

    [class*="col-"].gutter {
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
</style>

<div class="container mt-5">
    <div class='row mb-n3 gutter'>
        <div class='col-4 col-sm-2 mb-3 gutter text-center text-light '>
            <div class="col bg-primary">1</div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-4 col-sm-2 mb-3 gutter text-center text-light '>
            <div class="col bg-secondary">2</div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-4 col-sm-2 mb-3 gutter text-center text-light '>
            <div class="col bg-success">3</div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-4 col-sm-2 mb-3 gutter text-center text-light '>
            <div class="col bg-danger">4</div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-4 col-sm-2 mb-3 gutter text-center text-light '>
            <div class="col bg-warning">5</div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-4 col-sm-2 mb-3 gutter text-center text-light '>
            <div class="col bg-info">6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  
<div class="container-fluid bg-dark text-light" style="height: 200px;">
    <p>A filler div to show that there can be a space between the rows of elements on a small screen, but no space below the row, if you don&rsquo;t want one.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Any idea how I can put a little margin between these elements?  When I added mr-2 to the first 5 of 6 items it now wraps the sixth item to a new row.

Comment: I updated my answer to your question to have a little margin between elements. I don't know if my changes will work on your accepted answer.