# 5 equal columns for large screen only - bootstrap 5

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

**I am editing this question to make my question more clear.**

I know that bootstrap considers a screen as 12 columns and you can use classes like `col-md-` or `col-lg-` to code it for different screens. What my question is: **is there a way i can code my divs to be in 5 equal width divs for medium and large screens but for sm or xs screens the divs take full width i-e 12 columns?**

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">
      1 of 5
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      2 of 5
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      3 of 5
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      4 of 5
   </div>
   <div class="col">
      5 of 5
   </div>
</div>
```

**The above code will create 5 equal columns for all screens - But I want it to be only for medium and large screens. For small screens, I want a full-width column.**

Comment: The downvote could be because there have been many _similar_ questions over the years, and also because this is all quite clear in [Bootstrap's very good documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/). Don't let it discourage you. Keep coding and keep posting!

Comment: Here's one near duplicate, for example: [How can I change Bootstrap columns sizing based on screen size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67154881/change-bootstrap-columns-sizing-based-on-screen-size) The question is a bit different, but the answer shows the same solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#responsive-classes) - you need to use `col-md` to specify that you only want columns on medium screens or larger.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-md">
      1 of 5
   </div>
   <div class="col-md">
      2 of 5
   </div>
   <div class="col-md">
      3 of 5
   </div>
   <div class="col-md">
      4 of 5
   </div>
   <div class="col-md">
      5 of 5
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.aligin {
  margin: auto !important;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row aligin">
  <div class="col-md">
    1 of 5
  </div>
  <div class="col-md">
    2 of 5
  </div>
  <div class="col-md">
    3 of 5
  </div>
  <div class="col-md">
    4 of 5
  </div>
```

Comment: Custom CSS is rarely necessary for layout in Bootstrap. Also, `col-md` isn't a valid Bootstrap class.